Significant and Strange Time Discrepancy Between Direct Solution and Generic Callback-Based Approach for Solving an Instance
I am attempting to solve a MILP using logic-based Benders decomposition (LBBD) via generic callbacks, but I have encountered some unexpected behavior.
When solving the MILP directly, the problem is solved in just a few seconds. However, when I attempt to solve the same instance using LBBD (with a class implementing the generic callback interface), where the original problem is set as the master problem (i.e., no constraints are relaxed in the master problem), the solver fails to find the optimal solution. Theoretically, both approaches should solve the same problem (I verified this by checking the LP files), and they use the same set of heuristics and cut (note that since the master problem is the original problem, no user cuts are invoked, and no feasible nodes are pruned from the tree).
While I expect some differences in performance between the two approaches, such a significant issue is puzzling to me. Has anyone encountered a similar situation or have any insights on this?

When you say that the solver fails to find the optimum, do you mean it hits a time limit before finishing the solve or do you mean that it finds an "optimal" solution that is inferior to the actual optimum? If the former, have you tried extending the time limit?

Thank you very much for your reply.
My problem is exactly the first case; the solver reaches its time limit but is unable to close the gap. I haven't extended the time limit, but how does it matter? Do you suspect that the optimal solution is somehow discarded from the search space and the solver will never reach it?

Since you mentioned "generic callbacks", I assume you are using CPLEX. (Neither the title nor problem text specify the solver.)

The presence of a generic callback (or a legacy lazy constraint callback) alters some of the presolve operations and cut additions that CPLEX performs. That could account for CPLEX taking longer to solve the problem. It should not result in CPLEX failing to solve the problem (given unlimited time and memory), nor should it result in an incorrect solution.
